# Play 2.6 Akka Clusters

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-cluster

I'm trying to create Akka Clusters inside my Play Application, with the documentation provided in lightbend and Akka Documentation, I have managed to create a cluster with 2 nodes running 10 instances of the actor, however I have been stuck since a day, trying to access a single instance of the node cluster.
So, Trial1.scala creates the first node for the cluster and keeping on listening till some node joins. Trial1 uses the system and config created in the SystemTest.scala.

Trialagain.scala is the second node with 10 instances of itself and joins with the first cluster.

These two parts are working fine.

Now when I try to use any instance from this cluster, I figured I'd just need to use actorselection to get any instance of the already present node, do correct me if I'm going wrong, TrialThird is where Im trying to do that,  when I don't use actorselection and use actorof, pretty sure, it creates its own instance and runs easy, but when I use actorselection to access the node instances, it throws following error.
    [Cluster1-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://Cluster1/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] without sender to Actor[akka://Cluster1/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.

Trial.scala

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorSystem, Address, Props}
import akka.cluster.Cluster
import akka.cluster.routing.{ClusterRouterPool, ClusterRouterPoolSettings}
import akka.routing.RoundRobinPool
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object Trial{
def main(args: Array[String]):Unit= {
 val system= SystemTest.system
   system.actorOf(Props[Trial].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(10)),name="Trial1")
 Cluster(system).join(Address("akka.tcp","Cluster1","127.0.0.1",2222))
}
}

class Trial extends Actor with ActorLogging{
import context.dispatcher
override def receive: Receive={
case msg => log.info("Got message: {}",msg)
}
}
```

Trialagain.scala

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorSystem, Address, Props}
import akka.cluster.Cluster
import akka.cluster.routing.{ClusterRouterPool,  ClusterRouterPoolSettings}
import akka.routing.RoundRobinPool
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


object Trialagain{
val conf=
  """
  |akka {
  |
  |  log-dead-letters = 1
  |  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
  |  # extensions = ["akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterReceptionistExtension"]
  |
  |  actor {
  |    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  |  }
  |  remote {
  |    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
  |    netty.tcp {
  |      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
  |      port = 2551
  |    }
  |  }
  |}
  |

""".stripMargin
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(conf)
val system = ActorSystem("Cluster1", config)
system.actorOf(Props[Trialagain].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(10)),name="Trialagain")
Cluster(system).join(Address("akka.tcp","Cluster1","127.0.0.1",2222))
}

}

class Trialagain extends Actor with ActorLogging{
override def receive: Receive={
case msg => log.info("Got message: {}",msg)
}
}
```

SystemTest.scala

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory


object SystemTest {

val conf=
"""
  |akka {
  |
  |  log-dead-letters = 1
  |  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
  |  # extensions = ["akka.contrib.pattern.ClusterReceptionistExtension"]
  |
  |  actor {
  |    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  |  }
  |  remote {
  |    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
  |    netty.tcp {
  |      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
  |      port = 2222
  |
  |    }
  |  }
  |
  |  cluster {
  |    seed-nodes = [
  |      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551",
  |      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]
  |  }
  |}
  |
  |

""".stripMargin
val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(conf)
val system = ActorSystem("Cluster1", config)
sys.addShutdownHook(system.terminate())
}
```

TrialThird.scala

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Address, Props}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future


class TrialThird extends Actor{
override def receive: Receive = ???
}


object TrialThird {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val system= ActorSystem("Cluster1")
val router= system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://Cluster1@127.0.0.1:2222/user/Trial1")
Future{
router ! "hello"
}
} 
}
```

Comment: It might be useful to give some more background about what you are trying to accomplish. Often the slightly higher-level 'clustering' features are more convenient compared to working with routers and actor selection directly.

Comment: I just want multiple instances of similar Actors running in a node inside a cluster, now when I call the actor from somewhere else, in my cases inside my controller (MVC), I want it to access the instances of the actor inside the node, in the above code, I make the cluster which listens to the next node and joins, after which if I call the actor from any other class, it creates a new instance of the actor itself, any solution I have written the above code using help from Akka documentations.